# Django реализация сложного сценария с динамическими формами

Tags: javascript, python, django, веб-программирование

В процессе разработки своего тренировочного проекта появилась потребность реализовать следующий сценарий для ввода параметром n количества деталей в БД.

Страница должна представлять собой произвольный набор форм для ввода информации по каждой детали.

Форма для каждого изделия представляет собой набор статических полей (серийный номер, дата, тип и тд) и набор динамического набора полей характеристик, зависящего от типа изделия.

Примерная визуализация задумки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более опытных коллег прошу помочь навести на путь истинный в следующих вопросах:

1) Как динамически менять формсет представляющий собой форму для каждой детали в зависимости от выбора в поле type. 

2) Как сделать формсет, формсетов, для добавления произвольного количества "строк" в форму.

Кусочек models.py для сценария:

```
class Product_2_characteristic(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Product',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    characteristic_of_product_id = models.ForeignKey('Characteristic_of_product', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    operation_history_id = models.ForeignKey('Operation_history', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # Беру по полю оперейшин_хистори для удобства
        return reverse('product_2_characteristic-detail', args=[str(self.operation_history_id_id)])


class Product(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type_of_product_id = models.ForeignKey('Type_of_product', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Assembly = models.ManyToManyField('Product')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Operation_history(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type_of_operation_id = models.ForeignKey('Type_of_operation', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    type_of_defect_id = models.ForeignKey('Type_of_defect', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    employess_id = models.ForeignKey('Employess', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


class Type_of_operation(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Type_of_defect(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

К сожалению, задача поставила меня в тупик и внятных вариантов в части views и forms я предоставить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Крайне сочувствую вам, что вы наткнулись на туже задачу, что я пару месяцев назад.

Решения из коробки - нет.

Для формсетов с формсетами можете попробовать [это](https://blog.bullgare.com/2011/01/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-django/) либо [это](https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-use-nested-formsets-in-django/) (может одно и тоже, смотрел про примерным признакам, знакомому коду), либо пишите сами, указывая префиксы вложенных формсетов вмсесте с префиксами рожительских. Много JS кода будет для динамического добавления.

Что касается разных наборов полей, могу посоветовать либо подгружать их через AJAX и вставлять в HTML, запрашивая нужный тип формы (будет много форм), либо делать как ModelForm и собирать форму динамически. Поля и их тип можно хранить в БД в JSON (в принципе можно все так хранить, но полагаю вам нужно потом работать с этими объектами, так что для каждой модели своя таблица, а формы для них в JSON в отдельной таблице)

Вот кстати хороший, но древний вариант для динамической формы (https://habr.com/ru/post/46845/)

В принципе, вашу задачу можно решить, написав много JS и AJAX, постоянно подменивая формы и отправляя их по AJAX на свой URL для сохранения